# Download a single file at a time

Tags: c#

So I have this function to automatically check for updates, and it uses XML to check for updates.

The code is the following:

```
        foreach (XElement update in patchXml.Descendants("update"))
        {
            // Defines XElements, strings and ints

            if (serverPatch > localPatch)
            {
                // Using webclient downloadAsync, downloads ALL newest patches, not just one (which is what I don't want it to do)
            }
            else
            {
                // Continues to program
            }
        }
```

And then DownloadFileCompleted handles the files and applies them to the files which needs update.

How can I only download a single file at a time?

Comment: Don't use the async version of the download method.

Comment: @MatiasCicero Is it really just that simple?

Comment: Yes. the file will be downloaded synchronously, blocking your current executing thread and preventing the next files to be downloaded until the current one has finished.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this and report back as soon as I'm done!